# Why can't Beautifulsoup find a table on this webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use Google Colab to webscrap a table from [this website](https://www.stadiumgaming.gg/rank-checker?pokemon=WALREIN) but when I run the code below I receive empty brackets.

```
import urllib.request as url
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = f'https://www.stadiumgaming.gg/rank-checker?pokemon=Walrein'
html = url.urlopen(page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML,'html5lib').findAll('td')
print(soup)
```

Output:
`[]`

How can I find the table on this page so that it can be parsed into a dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't find a table using Beautifulsoup ffrom this  webpage because it's dinamically populated by `JavaScript` and bs4 can't parse JS. but you can mimic bs4, pandas with selenium

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

webdriver_service = Service("./chromedriver") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service)
url = 'https://www.stadiumgaming.gg/rank-checker?pokemon=WALREIN'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(3)

table=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

df = pd.read_html(str(table))[1]
print(df.iloc[1:,0:9])
```

**Result:**

```
    Rank       IVs    CP   Lvl       %     Atk     Def  Sta    Prod
1   2072  10/10/10  1483    20   94.97  114.70  111.12  150  1911.8
2      1   0/12/15  1499    21  100.00  111.41  115.09  157  2013.1
3      2   0/13/14  1500    21   99.89  111.41  115.70  156  2010.9
4      3   0/13/13  1497    21   99.89  111.41  115.70  156  2010.9
5      4   0/14/12  1498    21   99.78  111.41  116.31  155  2008.6
6      5   1/14/10  1500    21   99.68  112.02  116.31  154  2006.6
7      6   0/15/11  1499    21   99.65  111.41  116.92  154  2006.1
8      7   0/15/10  1496    21   99.65  111.41  116.92  154  2006.1
9      8    1/15/8  1498    21   99.55  112.02  116.92  153    2004
10     9   3/15/15  1499  20.5   99.53  111.89  115.52  155  2003.5
11    10   1/10/15  1499    21   99.48  112.02  113.86  157  2002.6
```